# Unable to update DoDataExchange method : VS 2000 Project converted to Visual Studio 2008 or VS 2010 Options

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, mfc

I am having a problem. I have a project "MicroSIP" which is used for 
SIP based call voice over IP. I am running it into VS 2010 and I need 
to customize it according to my need. For this as soon as I edit the 
main dialog ( Dialer ) and add some other controls ( like edit control 
of CEdit) and add member variable for from wizard of "Add Variable", 
it shows the message "unable to update DoDataExchange method". 
More over if getting reference of newly placed "Edit Control" in the 
program , it has NULL pointer or undefined reference.

It crashes now inside `DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_EDIT_Address, MacAddressEditCtrl );` where `IDC_EDIT_Address` is the `id` and `MAcAddressEditctrl` is `CWnd` object.

```
void AFXAPI DDX_Control(CDataExchange* pDX, int nIDC, CWnd& rControl)
{
    if ((rControl.m_hWnd == NULL) && (rControl.GetControlUnknown() == NULL))    // not subclassed yet
    {
        ASSERT(!pDX->m_bSaveAndValidate);

        pDX->PrepareCtrl(nIDC);   //it crashes here...
      HWND hWndCtrl;
      pDX->m_pDlgWnd->GetDlgItem(nIDC, &hWndCtrl);
        if ((hWndCtrl != NULL) && !rControl.SubclassWindow(hWndCtrl))
        {
            ASSERT(FALSE);      // possibly trying to subclass twice?
            AfxThrowNotSupportedException();
        }
#ifndef _AFX_NO_OCC_SUPPORT

    else
    {
     if (hWndCtrl == NULL)
     {
        if (pDX->m_pDlgWnd->GetOleControlSite(nIDC) != NULL)
        {
           rControl.AttachControlSite(pDX->m_pDlgWnd, nIDC);
        }
     }
     else
     {
           // If the control has reparented itself (e.g., invisible control),
           // make sure that the CWnd gets properly wired to its control site.
           if (pDX->m_pDlgWnd->m_hWnd != ::GetParent(rControl.m_hWnd))
               rControl.AttachControlSite(pDX->m_pDlgWnd);
     }
    }
#endif //!_AFX_NO_OCC_SUPPORT

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized myself that I placed and written the code of another OnInitDialog..
It was main dialog's control of whole I was trying to manipulate of another dialog's code.
Thanks